# html5 input type text with regex for pattern in mobile

Tags: regex, html, textinput

Hi so I'm trying to get a pattern for an input type text that shows numbers and a dot. Going over the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) I see that one can use basically regex to pull only numbers in the keyboard. Something like

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>
```

I'm looking for a way to have exactly this but also a dot in the keyboard. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just include a dot in the character class.

```
[0-9.]*
```

Note that this is also "zero or more digits and dots."

Comment: yeah this gives me the normal keyboard. I'm looking for the phone keyboard but also with a dot

Comment: yeah I think this is the only option all though it gives me everything else not just numbers and a dot. Thanks for that!